# NGINX conf file messed up

Tags: macos, nginx, terminal

So I accidentally messed up my NGINX `.conf` file. I've uninstalled NGINX and reinstalled, but yet the file is the same. So here's my question. Is there a way to completely uninstall it, and get a clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove everything in the conf folder and grab the default conf from the tar.gz here - http://nginx.org/en/download.html

Comment: Why is it when I uninstall the file doesn't change?

Comment: It is highly possible that the configuration files didn't get removed during the uninstallation, and the new installation doesn't overwrite the old conf files. You could try uninstall again and check the conf folder.